# jQuery selector $('table td:eq(2) a') get the cell only from the first row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

`$('table td:eq(2) a')` return the `a` tag of the third column but only from the first row.

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a bug but it is definitely confusing.  What will give you the result you expect is:

```
$('table td:nth-child(3) a')
```

While :nth-child and :eq seem very similar the behavior can be quite different as can be seen from the result you expected.

The jQuery documentation on this can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).
It states:

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements. With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class. With :eq(n)  only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of any other element, and the nth one is selected.

In simpler words, eq(2) will select the third element in the while result set while :nth-child(3) will select the 3 child of its parent. And in this case the parent will be its tr.

Comment: I think this can be wrong, think about when there are 5 columns on each row. "table td:nth-child(3)" will select third column in first row and first column in second row...

Comment: you say ":nth-child(3) will select the 3 child of its parent. And in this case the parent will be its tr." if this is true, how can I do same with table as parent?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not a bug. It matches the anchor tag in third element in the set matched by `table td`, so it's in the third cell in the table.

(If the table was only two cells wide, you would get the first cell in the second row.)

Comment: That's OK. but Why the third cell in the second row doesn't include?

Comment: as Guffa explained, table td get ALL the td elements in the table. Then eq(2) selects the 2nd one from the entire set.

Answer (score 2):

In simple word,

According to your code  `$('table td:eq(2)')` returns third `td` in `table` as strting from index=0 it will pick third `td` see below

[image]

for `$('table td:eq(4)')` result would be fifth `td` of the table see below

[image]

to select whole second column use :nth-child() index starts from 1

ex: `$('table td:nth-child(2)')`

[image]

I hope you get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$('table td:eq(2)')` will select all `'table td'`, and the index `eq(2)` will select the third `td` from this collection. so there is just one `a` under third column.